# How to set another object inside another object | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I don't know if this question's been answered yet but I'd still ask. Pretty confused over this one, and it might be simple but nonetheless, here goes:

I want to turn this **already set object** (meaning i have no access to it, just getting it from the server):

```
Object: {

    test1: 'test1',
    test2: 'test2',
    test3: 'test3'

}
```

to (basically just add another object inside it):

```
Object: {

    test1: 'test1',
    test2: 'test2',
    test3: 'test3',
    test4: 'test4'

}
```

Not sure if this was asked or answered before but if I can get an answer here to clarify this, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> basically just add another object inside it

You're not adding an object inside it; you're adding a property.

There are several ways.

```
Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'test4', { value: 'test4 })
```

This will return the object, which could be handy.

Or, of course, just

```
myObject.test4 = 'test4'
```

You can use the "merge" or "extend" features in many libraries, which would be useful if adding more than one new property:

```
_.extend     (myObject, { test4: 'test4' })  // Underscore
$.extend     (myObject, { test4: 'test4' })  // jQuery
Ember.merge  (myObject, { test4: 'test4' })  // Ember
Object.assign(myObject, { test4: 'test4' })  // ES6
```

Comment: Right, of course just straight up define it as an object. funny I asked this because it wasn't working before on other projects but it worked here. Anyways, thanks :) I'll accept this answer as soon as it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object like this:

```
people = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 18
};
```

You can simply add one attribute to it this way:

```
people.hairColor = 'black';
```

Than your people object will be like:

```
people = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 18,
    hairColor: 'black'
};
```